# Doxygen parse javadoc?

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm curious as to if Doxygen parses Javadoc comments? - that is, does doxygen accept something alike this:

```
/**
   Greet with a "Hello" message.
   @param a string containing the name of the person or entity
   @ret return a string containing "Hello" and the name of the greeted person or entity.
*/
public String sayHello(string name)
{
   return "Hello" + name;
}
```

And another thing, is there a more correct way of doing these comments, doxygen style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doxygen accepts similar syntax to JavaDoc, but not exactly the same.  Your example comment would be recognized, except for the `@ret` command.  The correct command in doxygen is `@return`.

Here are the examples on doxygen's website:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html